# Can't bind my app to sql server DB

Tags: android, sql-server, eclipse

hi this is a fragment but i tried it in an activity and it throw the same error i don't know what to do if the error has thrown because of my sql server or there is something i should do so i hope someone would help me
this is the exception : 
**04-16 07:53:06.693: E/Error(1144):  Network error IOException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 1433): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)**

```
public class TopStories extends Fragment {
ListView lv = null;
Connection connx = null;
SimpleAdapter sa = null;
String sqlreq = "select * from news";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection cnx() //connection to sqlserver
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnUrl = null;

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/PFFDB;ssl=required";
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);

    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        Log.e("Error", " "+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        Log.e("Error", " "+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("Error", " "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}



public void SqlQuery(String SqlCmnd) 
{
    connx = cnx();
    ResultSet rs;
    try 
    {
        Statement stm = connx.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery(SqlCmnd);
        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A", rs.getString("title"));
            datanum.put("B", rs.getString("idnews"));
            data.add(datanum);
        }
        String[] from = {"A","B"};
        int [] views ={R.id.Titleid,R.id.ArticleID};
        sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.model, from, views);
        lv.setAdapter(sa);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", " "+e.getMessage());
    }

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

}


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //newsv = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);




    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.topstories, container,false);
}


@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SqlQuery(sqlreq);

    }


@Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();


    }


@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }


@Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }


@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();
    }


@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }


@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDetach();
    }
```

}

Comment: Does the database require a username and password, and, if so, how are you transmitting it?

Comment: nop i use the windows auth and i did read that ssl=required have the same role as integrated security so i used it